# How to exclude the time taken by the @AfterClass method?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I ran the following test class and it reported that the first test took 2 seconds and the second took 4 seconds. I expected JUnit to output the time for each test case without putting into account the time of the `@BeforeClass` or `@AfterClass` method.

But obviously it includes the time of the `@AfterClass` method into only the last test case, which doesn't make sense at all if you ask me.

Is there a way make JUnit output the times only for the time taked for each test case ?

```
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TimeTest {
    @Test
    public void test1() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree it's not entirely correct, but how is it important? It's a test, not a profiler run.

Comment: If the time taken to run the test isn't accurate then it shouldn't be reported. If it's reported, then it must be accurate.

Comment: Well, what do you run it with? Sounds to me it's pretty much an issue of tooling. In IntelliJ, I don't think there's an individual item for "setup" and "shutdown", but if the time were left out, it wouldn't be much more accurate, would it? For Maven builds, it's the total time that's most interesting.

Comment: I run it using Eclipse IDE, nothing fancy or tricky. The time reported for a single test is for that test only. The problem occurs when reporting the time for the last test as it includes the "shutdown" time too.

Answer (score 0):

`@BeforeClass` & `@AfterClass` run ones for all tests

what you should do is to use `@Before`, and `After` instead, with the help of an instance variable

```
public class TimeTest {

    long timeInMillis=0;

    @Before
    public void before(){
       timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    @After
    public static void after() throws InterruptedException {
        long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - timeInMillis;
        // log the diff or cast it to seconds
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not the first one with such a problem. There are a lot of examples of time logging on the internet.

I suggest you to use JUnit `@Rule`s to solve your problem and avoid a code-duplication. (You don't want to write `timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()` in each test class, do you?)

[There is an example](https://www.javarticles.com/2016/02/junit-stopwatch-rule-example.html) of rule implementation